# If a die is tossed 10 times and six of the tosses are 1s, what is the expected number of 2s in the 10 tosses?

Tags: probability, dice

If a dice is tossed $10$ times and six of the tosses are $1$s,

> What is the expected number of $2$s in the $10$ tosses?

I don't know if I'm overthinking this or not. Do I need to include the $6$ tosses that rolled a $1$ or am I just using the $4$ rolls that are left with the probability that rolling a $2$ is $\frac{1}{5}$, since no more $1$s can be rolled?

Comment: The second.....

Comment: The problem is the original statement is ambiguous as whether it means "at least six 1's" or "exactly six 1's". The latter case much simpler since its equivalent to 4 rolls of a five-sided die. The former case, however, is NOT equivalent to 4 rolls of an ordinary die. See comments below answers for a little more on this.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it's a fair die, you'd only worry about the remaining 4 rolls.

This would give you 4(1/6), with probability of rolling a 2 as 2/3.

Comment: The remaining 4 don't have 1s, tjat affects the probability for 2.

Comment: In that case, yes 1/5. Maybe revise your question, as I'm not sure the problem is clear.

Comment: @BenCorson I mean, they didn't say _exactly_ 6 of the ten tosses were 1s, but it's not an unreasonable assumption. Besides, if they really do mean "at least 6", then I suspect that that's not as easy to take into account as you make it out to be.

Comment: @Arthur, I was initially nonplussed with your suspicion. Then I replaced ten tosses with two, and six $1$'s with one.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you interpret the question.

If you want to know the number of expected $2$'s in $10$ tosses (i.e. the number expected before doing any trials) then the answers is $\frac{1}{6} \times 10 = 10/6 = 1+ \frac{4}{6}$ths or $1.\overline6$ reccuring. This is the expected number of $2$'s in any set of $10$ tosses using a fair die. (You could argue that even if you rolled $10$ $1$'s, the expected number of $2$'s would still be $1.\overline6$)

If you are asking the number of expected $2$'s in a set of $10$ tosses where there have been $6$ rolls so far and all are $1$'s (and that you could potentially roll more ones), then it is $4 \times \frac{1}{6} = \frac{4}{6} = 0.\overline6$ recurring
(again assuming that you are using a fair die)

If all $10$ tosses have been carried out by someone else (ie all results are concluded) and exactly $6$ were $1$'s (no potential for any more) then you are correct in assuming $\frac{1}{5}$th chance per trial for a $2$. In this case the expected number would be $4 \times \frac{1}{5} = \frac{4}{5} = 0.8$

However - this is assuming the die has not been tampered with.

Comment: Not sure why the downvote - Help a newbie out and at least explain what I did to get a -1 :(

Comment: You don't deserve the down vote, there are some intolerant types around here as with every on line community. The difficult case is where you are given precisely: "At least six of the rolls were 1's". This is not equivalent to " the first six rolls were 1's", which you see by looking at the smaller case of 2 rolls with at least one roll of 1.

Comment: I think if you strictly interpret the question, the number of 1's is irrelevant to the expected number of 2's in 10 tosses. However, the rest of the question seems to indicate a focus on the remaining tosses. I think it would be clearer if the question was 'Given the six out of ten tosses were 1's, of the four remaining tosses, what would be the expected number of 2's?'  (and this is the reason for multiple answers on my part).

Comment: Well that would be simpler but it's a perfectly valid math problem to ask, for example, if you roll a pair of dice and you are given that at least one roll was a 1, what is the expected number of 2's. The answer is 2/11. The generalization of this to 10 rolls with at least 6 1's is a perfectly well defined, but not easy, problem.

Comment: I would still argue that the expected number of 2's would be a constant regardless of how many rolls have taken place and their results. If you had six rolls, you would expect one to be a 2. If you then roll six 2's, the expected number of the six rolls to be a 2 would still be only one. Semantics perhaps?

Comment: Of course it's semantics, the original problem statement was ambiguous. Are you familiar with the classic "Given that a family with 2 children has a boy, what's the probability that they have two boys." The context in which the information "has a boy" was given determines whether the answer is 1/2 or 1/3 or "could be 1/3 or 1/2 depending...". But it's not about timing of the question, it's about what was the possible extra information we might have received when we did in fact receive "has a boy", or something like that.

Comment: You're right - it's not about the timing, it's the interpretation. updating answer :)

Answer (score 0):

If a fair die is used, we can indeed use the knowledge that exactly six $1$s were thrown. Each remaining value has a probability of $\frac{1}{5}$ of being rolled, so if $X$ is the number of times a $2$ is rolled, we find:

$$E[X] = 4 \cdot \frac{1}{5} = 0.8$$

Alternatively, using the definition of $E[X]$ along with the [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution):

$$E[X] = \sum_{i=0}^{4} i P(X = i)$$

$$= 1 \cdot {4 \choose 1} \cdot \frac{4^3}{5^4} + 2 \cdot {4 \choose 2} \cdot \frac{4^2}{5^4} + 3 \cdot {4 \choose 3} \cdot \frac{4^1}{5^4} + 4 \cdot {4 \choose 4} \cdot \frac{4^0}{5^4} = \frac{4^4 + 12 \cdot 4^2 + 12 \cdot 4 + 4}{5^4} = \frac{500}{625} = 0.8$$